# How to use summernote to pass content and images at same time via ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, summernote

I am trying to create a wp type text editor to upload image and content for a post. So I've used summernote as a text editor.

What I am trying to achieve is, I want to send the post content i.e the text content and the media that are attached to the post at the same time. So that i can process it at the same time.

Following is my HTML Code.

```
<textarea name="post_content" id="post_content" class="form-control round post_content"></textarea>
```

I am using the following jQuery Code:

```
$('#post_content').summernote(
                {
                    height: 300,
                    placeholder: "Type Your Post Content...",
                    toolbar: [
                                ['style', ['style']],
                                ['style', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strikethrough', 'superscript', 'subscript', 'clear']],
                                ['fontname', ['fontname']],
                                ['fontsize', ['fontsize']],
                                ['color', ['color']],
                                ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']],
                                ['height', ['height']],
                                ['table', ['table']],
                                ['insert', ['link', 'picture', 'video', 'hr', 'readmore']],
                                ['view', ['fullscreen', 'codeview']]
                                // ['help', ['help']]
                            ],
                    callbacks:
                        {
                            onImageUpload: function(files, editor, welEditable)
                                {
                                    for(var i = files.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                                        {
                                            sendFile(files[i], this);
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                });

            function sendFile(file, el)
                {
                    var form_data = new FormData();
                    form_data.append('file', file);
                    $.ajax({
                        data: form_data,
                        type: "POST",
                        url: '/image-upload.php',
                        cache: false,
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false,
                        success: function(url) {
                            $(el).summernote('editor.insertImage', url);
                        }
                    });
                }
```

The problem with the current code is that it's uploading the image directly to the server. I want to send the image and the content at the same time on a click of a button so that I can store the text code in DB and get the images out, process them in various size and store it in DB too.

But i am not able to figure out how can i achieve it.

Comment: its about how summernote works, if you use `('editor.insertImage', url)` it expects to find the image under that url, thats why the uploads are sent directly and it makes perfect sense, why not process the images in image-upload.php ?

Comment: i want the content and images to be sent at once when i click the button publish. So that i can process it.

Comment: still, i dont think its correct to store the images in DB too, why dont you try to implement the wordrpress mediathek? You just shouldnt use the summernote function but include your own file input in your form.

Comment: is there any demo tutorial to create or implement it?

Comment: there is a javascript api for the wp media https://codex.wordpress.org/Javascript_Reference/wp.media and lots of tutorials if you research properly, your goal would be to choose an image and return the URI of it to summernote

Comment: You could base64 encode image either at insert or  before upload.

Answer (score 0):

As part of @cloudformatter, there is an option to embedLocalImages. This essentially uses jQuery to take some content, find all images, put them on a canvas, scrape them as base64 encoded data and then replace the image URL with the base64-encoded data. This was written only to embed images that are local in that project (meaning you are running in localhost) because it would send the data remote to be formatted and of course, the remote formatter has no idea where "http://localhost/myimage.jpg" is.

You can find it in the http://www.cloudformatter.com/CSS2PDF code, the relevant part is posted here for you. You could adopt a similar method to replace all the images with base64 equivalents as such the data would be inline.

Of course, you are storing long term which means that the images would not update if they changed at some http:// location. You could add something like a data-url attribute to store the original URL and if you bring the data back out for update, and use that URL to replace the base64 encoded data.

```
embedLocalImages: function(dest) {
    jQuery(dest).find('img').each(function(index) {
        var img = this;
        var imageUrl = img.src;
        if (imageUrl.indexOf(xepOnline.Formatter.getBase()) != -1){
             var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
             var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
             canvas.height = img.height;
             canvas.width = img.width;
             ctx.drawImage(img,0,0, img.width, img.height);
             var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
             jQuery(img).attr('src', dataURL);
            canvas = null;
        }
    });
},
```